# What purpose does はめ serve in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

> ふたりではめあいしておかしいですね笑。

I know that
ふたりで means Two of us.
あいして means love.
おかしい means amusing, funny or comical.

But I'm not sure what purpose 'はめ' serves in the sentence and as such I can't really make sense of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: More context is needed to answer this question with confidence. In what kind of situation was this said, and what's the relationship of the two people here?

Comment: The two people are friends and it was said in a casual, friendly discussion type situation.@naruto

Answer (score 2):

This probably is 「二人で嵌【は】め合【あ】いしておかしいですね」.

- [嵌める](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%B5%8C%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) is a transitive verb which means "to wear (gloves/ring/etc)", "to insert (something into a slot/groove/hole)", "to entrap/frame (someone)", etc. I have no idea what the two people are actually doing because the object is omitted and the context is lacking.
- [合う](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%90%88%E3%81%86) after the masu-form of another verb means "to do ... together", "to do ... each other". 合い is the masu-form of 合う, and it's used as a noun ([here's why](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010)). 愛 is not relevant here.

The whole sentence would probably mean "It's funny that the two (of you/us) are doing 嵌める together/each other, lol"