# Meaning of: やりまくり

Tags: meaning, manga, parsing

I'm reading a manga and two people are having a conversation about a secret rendezvous (not sure yet if it's a rendezvous between the two people speaking or the people they are speaking about), when the man says:

> 今ごろお前の隣の部屋で / **ヤリまくり**だ

I believe the first part says "About this time at your neighbor's place," but I don't know what the second part means. I've looked it up on jisho.org and have inputted it into a few translators and nothing relevant comes up. I've even parsed it thinking that as 2 separate words (ヤリ＋まくり) something would ring a bell. The slash is where the sentence was broken up in the manga.

Please tell me what **ヤリまくり** means and if I've correctly translated the first part of the sentence as well.

Comment: As a virgin, I am too shy to answer this question.

Comment: @l'électeur: I had a feeling that it has something to do with "rolling in the hay," but wasn't sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's やり (masu-stem of やる) + まくり (masu-stem of まくる).

- やる: See the eleventh definition of [やる on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8B).
- masu-stem + まくる: "to do a lot of..." It's the second definition of [まくる on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%8D%B2%E3%82%8B).
- まくり is in the masu-stem form so that it works as a noun. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010).

Comment: omg, thanks! I thought it had to do with "doing the dirty" based on the context of the conversation, but I really wanted to make sure since I hadn't come across the phrase before.