# Is it correct to use verb stem + desu?

Tags: usage, verbs

I heard announcements (at the station in Tokyo):

> この電車は桜木町行きです /
>   この電車は桜木町へ行きです

(not sure, did I hear correctly?)

English version of the above:

> This train is bound for Sakuragichō.

So, I am asserting that we can use `verb stem + desu`. Is my assertion correct? Please explain.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010

Comment: @naruto you are great. Although your answers are little bit higher level (I am a beginner) but it always helps.

Comment: Naruto's answer on that linked question is much more comprehensive than mine. I strongly recommend anyone looking for a good answer to this question to go take a look.

Comment: @HalfwayDillitante I agree and I am reading his related link again and again to grasp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

In your example, that 「行き」 is actually a nounified(名詞化) version of the verb stem of「行く」.

「桜木町行き」 translates to "One that goes to Sakuragichou" or "Sakuragichou-bound".

The 「です」 is not required for the nounification. That applies for any other instance of verb-stem nounification. (i.e. うそなき- fake crying, すなあそび- sand play)

Answer (score 2):

This 行き isn't verb stem but a noun. Verb stem + desu is incorrect because a noun or attributive form of verbs and adjectives + の are placed before です.

連用形(continuous form) of verbs often become a noun.

In addition, この電車は桜木町へ行きです is unnatural but この電車は桜木町へ行きます is natural.