# Meaning of 切る in イシューを切る

Tags: meaning

In programming is very common to say things like "create an issue", "open a ticket", when you are asking for help or want to create a "topic" about the problem you wanna solve.

I realized that here in Japan people say things like:

> イシューを切る。イシューを切ってください。イシューを切っておきました。etc

[Reference](https://k-hyoda.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/04/27/200740#1-Issue%E3%82%92%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B)

I assume 切る here means something like "Create" or "Open", is it correct? I tried looking on [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8B) but the meanings there do not seem to fit.

Also, are there other words that take 切る with a similar meaning?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47682/5010

Comment: Interestingly I think “cut a new issue”, while never really used, is understandable in English too, by parallel to “cut a record” or “cut a check”. “Cut a new release” is used.

Comment: It's funny that I can understand it though people around me never use it. That said, I think 切る is more naturally used in ブランチを切る "create a branch".

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Oh I didn't know you could say ブランチを切る as well, thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it corresponds to the 8th definition of 切る on jisho.org:

> to issue (stamps, vouchers, etc.)

(But this "stamps" should be a translation mistake. We say [小切手](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B0%8F%E5%88%87%E6%89%8B)を切る but not 切手を切る. 小切手 and 切手 are completely different.)

デジタル大辞泉 and 明鏡国語辞典 give exactly the same definition (伝票や小切手などを発行する), but 明鏡 also describes the etymology:

> 伝票や小切手などを発行する。「小切手［伝票］を━」
>
> ▶ **切り離して発行することから。**

So 切る meaning "issue" is used with "ticket-like" things because cutting a ticket meant using it. "Ticket" is another name for what GitHub calls "issue", so this should be straightforward.

Comment: To issue a ticket makes a lot of sense, thank you!! It is just that the people that use it in my workplace (Japanese coworkers) always say 「issueを切っておいてください」, so it went over my head that I could think of it as "ticket" to make the connection of "issue a ticket", because "issue an issue" sounded a bit weird.