# Meaning of 首ひねり in the following sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, katakana, furigana, sports

A boxer has just managed to bring down his opponent landing his final punch. However, he surprisingly goes down too. [Here you can see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B6Eg.jpg). His trainer comments with this sentence:

> [スリッピングアウェー]{首　　ひ　　ね　　り}と同時に[とんで]{・・・}たか……ガキ〰〰〰

[image]

Why has 首ひねり been used as furigana for スリッピングアウェー? I researched 首ひねり and it is a sumo move in which a wrestler grab the opponent's head with one hand and with the other tries to throw him down, but, from the image, to me it looks as if the boxer bumped into or was hit by his opponent's arm after landing the final punch, though there are some spinning marks drawn. Not understanding this, I am also not able to understand the second part of the sentence. Could you help me understand why 首ひねり was used here and what is the general meaning of the sentence? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

首ひねり is obviously used to explain スリッピングアウェー, so it shouldn't be another difficult technical term. You can forget the sumo move.

首をひねる (literally "twist a neck") is a common set phrase (not specific to boxing) that means rotating or coking your head. Most of the time this phrase also figuratively means "to think deeply" or "to be puzzled" (similarly to "to shrug"), but its figurative meaning is not relevant now. In this context it just refers to the physical movement of rotating your head in order to absorb the shock of the punch, as illustrated in your picture and [this entry](https://ameblo.jp/yoshiki-0722/entry-11767937572.html). This may be obvious to you, but remember the [masu-stem can be used to nominalize a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010).

Next, I believe this [とぶ]{・・} is 意識が飛ぶ, which is another set phrase meaning "to faint". Note the dots beside とぶ, which often imply some slangy/derivative meaning of a word is used. For example [やる]{・・} might mean 殺る or "to kill".

Therefore the basic meaning of the sentence is "Boy, you had been unconscious since your last 首ひねり move".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To understand if 飛ぶ in this case means 'to faint' or 'to hit', could you please also explain the meaning of 「なっち‌​ゃいねえ」?

Comment: @Marco なっちゃいねえ means the same thing as [なってない](http://jisho.org/word/成ってない). He's saying "Riku is still no good" (because he fell after failing to do "slip-away").

Comment: Thank you @naruto for the clarification. So the trainer isn't actually admiring what his boxer did, as suggested in mackygoo's answer, right?

Comment: @Marco I think so. Is he a kind of person who admires a punch innocently at this critical moment when the puncher is down?

Comment: No, he is actually a strict trainer.

Comment: Also, the 〰〰〰 represents the trainer's irritation, which also shows that he's not happy with the boxer's passing out. The boxer failed to slip away from the opponent's punch and both boxers passed out, so it only ended up in 「相打ち」, no? 褒める要素ないやんｗ

Answer (score 0):

## English

> [スリッピングアウェー]{首ひねり}と同時にとんでたか……ガキ～

The above phrase is spoken by the second of Boxer A (RIKU). A "second" is a supporter of fighting sports such as boxing, that is explained [here](http://www.sportsdefinitions.com/boxing/Seconds.html).

Boxer B threw his left punch on boxer A just before the above phrase.
That punch hit straight on the face of Boxer A.

In fact, Boxer A turned his face to the right so as to ease the shock of the punch just before the punch reached straight on his face.
However, still the strong punch hit the face a bit and Boxer A fell on the ring.
Boxer A gave a punch against Boxer B with his left arm at the same time Boxer A makes a "首ひねり *neck twist*". Boxer A's punch was a punch that counterattacked when the opponent struck, so it is commonly called "counter punch", which is more powerful than an ordinary punch. As a matter of course, Boxer B also fell on the ring as he received the full force of the punch.

The following phrase was uttered by Boxer A's "second" at that time.

> [スリッピングアウェー]{首ひねり}と同時にとんでたか……ガキ～

"ガキ" is generally used for "わんぱく坊主｛ぼうず｝ *naughty boy* or *mischievous boy*", but Boxer A's second loved him and called him "ガキ" jokingly with affection. "You twisted your neck to the right and avoided the opponent's finishing punch as well as giving your punch to him. I could say that you performed a nice technique at once," he said with feeling admiration for Boxer A.
The explanation of "スリッピングアウェー *slipping away*" is [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC). According to it, it is a kind of boxing defense techniques: A higher skill where a boxer turns his face in the same direction as the direction in which the punch extends and relieves the impact.
In English there is no terminology of "slipping away", I think that it corresponds to "slipping" or "slip". It is explained [here](https://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-techniques/defense-techniques/how-to-slip-punches) as "How to Slip Punches".
Perhaps, I think, both "スリッピングアウェー lit. *slipping away*" and the Japanese translation of "首ひねり *neck twist*" for "スリッピングアウェー" are not established. So I think that the author of the comic book devised by putting 首ひねり to スリッピングアウェー like ふりがな to スリッピングアウェー to make the reader understand what スリッピングアウェー means.

"とんでたか (= 飛んでたか)" means "Wow, a punch was thrown (by GAKI or by Boxer A)" or "Wow, Boxer A threw a punch on Boxer B's face unconsciously". It is an expression used with admiring Boxer A's unintended fine play. As interpreted by naruto's answer interpreting Boxer A as "fainted", you cannot explain the fact that Boxer A and Boxer B both fell down on the ring.

[image]

## 日本語

> [スリッピングアウェー]{首ひねり}と同時にとんでたか……ガキ～

上記｛じょうき｝のフレーズは、ボクサーＡ(リク RIKU)の「セコンド *[second](http://www.sportsdefinitions.com/boxing/Seconds.html)*」からでたセリフです。
「セコンド」とはボクシングなどの格闘技｛かくとうぎ｝における介添人｛かいぞえにん｝のことです。

上記のセリフの直前｛ちょくぜん｝に、ボクサーＢが左腕｛ひだりうで｝によるパンチをボクサーＡに浴｛あ｝びせます。「相手｛あいて｝にパンチを打つ」ことを「パンチを浴びせる」と言います。
そのパンチはボクサーＡの顔面｛がんめん｝にまともに当たります。実際｛じっさい｝には、パンチがまともに当｛あ｝たる寸前｛すんぜん｝にボクサーＡは、顔｛かお｝を右｛みぎ｝に向｛む｝け（＝右回｛みぎまわ｝りに「首ひねり」をして）パンチの衝撃｛しょうげき｝を和｛やわ｝らげます。しかし、それでもパンチは顔に少し当たりボクサーＡはダウンします。
ボクサーＡが「首ひねり」をしたときと同時にボクサーＡは、自分の左腕でパンチをボクサーＢに向かって打ちます。ボクサーＡのパンチは相手が打ってきたときに反撃的｛はんげきてき｝に打つパンチですので一般に「カウンターパンチ」と言うもので、普通のパンチ以上に威力｛いりょく｝があります。そのパンチがボクサーＢにまともに当たりましたので、ボクサーＢは倒｛たお｝れます。

その時に、ボクサーＡの「セコンド」から出たセリフです。

> [スリッピングアウェー]{首ひねり}と同時にとんでたか……ガキ～

「ガキ」とは一般に「わんぱく坊主｛ぼうず｝」に対して言う言葉ですが、ボクサーＡのセコンドは愛情｛あいじょう｝を持ってボクサーＡのことを「ガキ」と呼んでいます。「首を右にひねって相手のパンチを避｛よ｝けたと同時によく自分のパンチを出したな。とっさに素晴｛すば｝らしい技｛わざ｝を出したな」とボクサーＡに対して感心｛かんしん｝して言ったセリフです。

スリッピングアウェーは、[ここ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC)にあります。ボクシングの防御｛ぼうぎょ｝の一種｛いっしゅ｝だと書かれています。英語ではスリッピングアウェーという用語は無く、単に、slippingあるいはslipというのだろうと思います。それについては[ここ](https://www.expertboxing.com/boxing-techniques/defense-techniques/how-to-slip-punches)に「How to Slip Punches」という題の説明があります。

多分｛たぶん｝「スリッピングアウェー」に対する「首ひねり」という日本語訳は定着｛ていちゃく｝していないと思いますが、[ここ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC)の説明｛せつめい｝を読｛よ｝み、漫画｛まんが｝の絵｛え｝を見ると、日本人には馴染｛なじ｝みの薄い「スリッピングアウェー」とはどのようなものかを説明するために、漫画の作者｛さくしゃ｝が「ふりがな」を振｛ふ｝るようにして「スリッピングアウェー」を工夫｛くふう｝して説明｛せつめい｝したものだと理解｛りかい｝できます。

「とんでたか（＝飛んでたか）」とは、「パンチが飛んでいたのか」という意味｛いみ｝で、ボクサーＡの左のパンチがボクサーＢの顔面｛がんめん｝に向｛む｝かって飛んだ（＝「パンチを打った」）ということを感嘆｛かんたん｝/ 感心{かんしん}して言った表現｛ひょうげん｝です。
なお、narutoさんの回答にあるように「とんだ」を「飛んだ＝気絶した」と解釈すると、ボクサーＡとボクサーＢとが同時にリング上に倒れている状況を説明できない。

[image]

Comment: だいたい同時に倒れたけど、主人公は倒れる際に一時的に気を失っていたのでどうして自分が倒れているのか分からず混乱している、という状況のように見えるので、「気を失っていた」で説明可能と思います。逆に称賛しながら「なっち‌​ゃいねえ」と言う人はいません。

Comment: @mackygoo thank you for your detailed explanation. To understand if 飛ぶ in this case means 'to faint' or 'to hit', could you please also explain the meaning of 「なっち‌​ゃいねえ」?

Comment: @Marco: "なっち‌​ゃいねえ" or "なっちャねェ" is a Kanto-style pronunciation that has changed phonologically from "成｛な｝ っていない".
"成る" means "to be completed" or "to be established", so "まだ、なっちャねェな" means "It has not been completed yet".

Comment: @Marco: When throwing a punch enough to defeat the opponent, a person places the weight of the body forward, so at the same time it is very difficult to take a defensive posture like "slipping away". As Boxer A performed a miraculous performance to throw a decisive punch at the same time while doing "slipping away", I think that the second admired his performance.

Comment: 相手と同時にノックダウンされ、このままでは数秒後に勝ちを逃すというこの状況で、"miraculous performance!" とは脳天気にも程があります。その画像も、状況説明のための大切なコマを削除して完全黙殺した上で、元からあるのと同程度の分量の言葉を創作で補ってしまったら、もう全く別物ですよ。あと（僕も最初勘違いしていましたが）リンクされている英語記事にあるスリッピングは斜め横に体を動かしてパンチを避ける動作のことで、このマンガの首ひねりとは別物です。