# difference between 好きになれる and 好きになる

Tags: grammar, word-choice

好きになる means fall in love/come to love, but what about 好きになれる? Does it mean "can come to love"? What does 好きになれる mean in this sentence?

先輩と一緒にいられないなら、わたしに誰が好きになれるの嫌だ

[image]

Comment: I believe the latter part of this sentence has some typo. And is this line said by a guy whose first-person pronoun is わたし?

Comment: @naruto I just checked and that's how it's written. And yes, it's a first person sentence.

Comment: There is really nothing between の and 嫌だ (か, question mark, comma, line break, ...)? Maybe can you share the image like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55847/5010)?

Comment: @naruto I just added a pic. Indeed, the only thing missing in the pic is the 嫌だ that is on the next page.

Comment: Okay, now this makes sense to me. (But why did you replace 先輩 with 彼女? I think this 先輩 probably refers to a guy...)

Comment: because I didn't want it to be ambiguous, in fact  senpai refers to the girl from pic related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 先輩と一緒にいられないなら、わたしに誰が好きになれるの？
>   If I cannot be with Sempai, then who (else) can I fall in love with?

This なれる is potential. This is a rhetorical question which actually implies "Sempai is the only person I can fall in love with." [誰が好き on its own is ambiguous](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30171/5010) ("who likes" vs "who does someone like"), but in this case it means "who do I like".

嫌だ on the next page should be just a one-word sentence, "No...", "No way", "I hate this (situation)", etc.

Comment: btw the first part of the sentence has 一緒 , doesn't that mean together?

Comment: 一緒にいる is to "be (together) with someone" but it's not exactly necessary to have that "together" there in English.

Comment: @naruto oh and the "can't" here means "not have the ability/not be able to do sth" because of the potential form right?
誰が好き you said this is ambiguous but can't it mean "who will fall in love with me" here? or is it impossible?

Comment: @Daniel It's either possibility or ability. "I don't have an ability to fall in love (with someone else)" may be an exaggerated statement, but basically she is so shocked that she feels she will not be in love with anyone else forever. "私 **（のこと）を** 誰が好きになれるの?" could have meant "who can fall in love with me? (i.e., no one will love me!)"

Comment: Thanks you, in the context of the whole story, it doesn't come across as too shocking, though. However, the nuance of the Japanese sentence confuses me a bit. Could that "can" be implying "I don't want"? As if the implication were "I don't want to fall for anyone (else) other than senpai"? I do agree that using "can" rather than "want" is a bit weird.

Comment: @Daniel Sort of, but "I cannot think of any possibility of being in love with someone other than sempai" may be closer.

Comment: Then what would someone mean if they said something like, 自分を好きになれる

Comment: @A.T.A. Such a sentence would make sense in the context of a self-loathing person being able to feel confident about themselves.

Comment: @naruto Who would 自分 refer to if a sentence like, "古の呪文よりも君の声で強くなれるの" came before it?

Comment: @A.T.A. What do you mean by "came before it"? Can you give the entire context?

Comment: @naruto I mean, the full clause goes as so, いにしえの呪文より君の声で強くなれるの　自分を好きになれる.

Comment: @A.T.A. Nothing changes. 自分を好きになれる refers to the speaker themself.