# Are those sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice

> その手紙を送るのに１００円かかった。
>
> その手紙の送るのに１００円かかった。
>
> その手紙の送りは１００円かかった。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) その手紙{てがみ}**を**送{おく}るのに１００円{えん}かかった。
>
> 2) その手紙**の**送るのに１００円かかった。
>
> 3) その手紙の**送り**は１００円かかった。

Among the three sentences, only the first one is correct, grammatical and natural-sounding.  It is just perfect.

Sentence #2 is incorrect for using  the first 「の」 as 「手紙」 is the direct object for the verb 「送る」.  We must use 「を」 instead.

Sentence #3 is also incorrect for using 「送り」.  We simply do not say 「その手紙の送り」. If you replaced 「送り」 by 「送料{そうりょう}」("postage"), the sentence would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence is the first one. The rest are wrong.

送り is a [tricky masu-stem-derived noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010) which appears only in several set phrases such as コマ送り, 早送り and 送り仮名.

If you want a noun-based expression, you can use 送料 and say:

> - その手紙の送料は100円だった。
> - その手紙の送料として100円かかった。

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct.

The second is incorrect for using a verb following the case particle 「の」.
If you want to use it, it'll be OK to say 「その手紙の送ることのために」。

The third is incorrect because the word 「送り」is rarely used alone.

Comment: 「その手紙の送ることために」: の is missing after こと, although "送ることのために100円かかった" would sound like you did not want to pay 100 yen.

Comment: その手紙を送るために is okay, but その手紙を送ることのために is unnaturally wordy and I would feel there were some reason to emphasize this part. Maybe it might look more or less closer to "It took me 100 yen TO SEND THE LETTER."

Comment: I'm sorry to have pressed the enter. I didn't know I have already sent it...

Comment: Correct. The reason why I added こと is the の. And I think 「のに」and 「ために」 are both objective. The mood only depends on the content afterwards, if any.