# Is it 脅かす【おどかす】 or 脅かす【おびやかす】?

Tags: multiple-readings

[This explanation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57114/31150) says,

> the target which 脅【おびや】かす threatens is not a person but abstract things such as a society, a nation, a status, peace, happiness and the like.

Is the reading of this sentence therefore the following?

> 豊【ゆた】かな海【うみ】が、ごみに脅【おびや】かされています
> *The rich ocean is threatened by garbage.*

豊【ゆた】かな rich

脅かす【おどかす】 threaten

脅かす【おびやかす】 threaten

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPCV5W3SPCKTZNB00F.html?iref=comtop_Opinion_01

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/92666/30454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it is おびやかす. Generally おどかす is used for "to scare".

- 人類が地球を脅{おびや}かしている現在 Modern times when humanity threatens earth

is ok to me, so I'm not sure "the target must be abstract" part of the explanation. Or some concrete things can be treated as abstract.

---

By the way it is 豊{ゆた}かな. 豊{ゆたか}な could be an okurigana variation and as a name, it can be 豊{ゆたか}.