# How to use 方 correctly

Tags: grammar, particles

Please read the passage:

> 四山市のごみの**捨て方**をお知らせします。4つのごみ箱があります。そして、**捨てる日**が違います。また、**捨てる所**も決まっています。注意してください。

Why should we say 捨てる日 and 捨てる所, but 捨て方？（方 is a noun too, just like 日 and 所）

＋

Why don't they use 捨てるの日 and 捨てるの所？

Comment: what reading are you using for 方?

Comment: @virmaior kata. I have the furigana for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [described in this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32299/5010), a masu-stem (aka 連用形, pre-masu form) has a noun-like quality, and they can *sometimes* directly connects to another noun like a compound. デジタル大辞泉 [defines](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/41597/meaning/m0u/) this type of 方【かた】 as a 接尾語 (suffix), and 明鏡国語辞典 defines it as a 造語成分. This means 方 is somewhat special and it never follows an attributive form.

捨てるの所 is plain wrong in Japanese. You can join a verb and a noun using the plain grammar of relative clauses, and there must not be の between them.

---

So which noun can follow a masu-stem?

方【かた】 and 様【よう】 can follow the masu-stem of any verb. 様 is usually used as part of the idiom ～ようがない/ある.

> - 魔物の倒し方を教わった。
> - 言葉に表し様がない不安を感じる。

Other nouns directly follow the masu-stem mainly as part of fixed expressions. `masu-stem + 時【どき】` means "suitable time for ～ing", "good chance for ～ing". `masu-stem + 所【どころ】` roughly means "point of ～ing". `masu-stem + 物` roughly means "thing to ～". You basically have to memorize them individually.

> - この商品は今が買い時【どき】です！
> - 市場は[書き入れ時](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E6%99%82)を迎えている。
> - 彼の説明には[とらえ所](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8D%95%E3%82%89%E3%81%88%E5%87%A6)がない。
> - この町の[見所](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A6%8B%E6%89%80)は駅前の桜並木です。
> - この議論の[落とし所](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D)が見つからない。
> - 自動販売機で飲み物を買った。

You usually cannot say ゴミの捨て所 or ゴミの捨て時 unless you're speaking jokingly.