# What is the nuance of using 連用形 with すれば rather than other forms of conditionals?

Tags: conditionals, renyōkei

Recently I came across

> 優希から直取りすれば逆転トップだぞ！？

And I was surprised to see it written like that rather than

> 優希から直取れば逆転トップだぞ！？

Is this a general thing that can be done with any 連用形 form of a verb? If not, then which ones? And what nuance does this carry, when compared with any of the "normal"?

Comment: 直取り is a noun (する). I don't think it can be conjugated in to 直取る at all. The word does not even appear in dictionaries.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I didn't see it as a word in the initial dictionary I used, and I didn't bother checking another since I just assumed 直 was used adverbably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 直取り is a [noun coined from the masu-stem of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010), also working as a suru-verb. There is no such a verb as 直取る. (直取れば may be used as a joke, though.)

お願い is a representative example of this; you can say お願いすれば but not お願う or お願えば. Other examples of suru-verbs that may look like godan/ichidan verbs include 馬鹿売れ, お使い, ひとっ飛び, 前借り, 大泣き and so on. Hmm, maybe this happens often with adverb-like prefixes?