# What difference will it make if I just write sentaku in the sentence "Ii tenki denaito, sentaku mono ga kawakimasen"?

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between sentaku and sentakumono?

Can't I just say "Ii tenki denaito, sentaku ga kawakimasen"?

Comment: Almost the same logic as: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85825/7810