# How to parse the form 上げしやすい？

Tags: conjugations

Someone is saying 初心者の子がいたから― レベル上げしやすい場所を教えてた (I showed a newbie a good place to level up).

Normally やすい is added to a verb without ます、but then what is the root of the form 上げします? I don't see 上げす in a dictionary.

Nor does 上げ　seem to exist in dictionary, as an independent word that I could combine with する.

Comment: Checking for レベル上げ would get more results. https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92/#:~:text=%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E2%80%90%E3%81%82%E3%81%92%E3%80%90%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%80%91,%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%80%82

Comment: [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Comment: Here 上げ is the masu-stem of 上げる [used as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is treating [レベル上げ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92/#:%7E:text=%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E2%80%90%E3%81%82%E3%81%92%E3%80%90%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%80%91,%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%80%82) as a noun and the verbal is レベル上げをする. And then for the -やすい construction you get the masu stem of する + レベル上げ: 上げしやすい