# What's the difference between 瞬く and 煌めき?

Tags: word-choice, song-lyrics

I was studying death note's first ending 「アルミナ」, and I found this phrase: 「流れる時間の中瞬く刹那的煌めきを」the dictionary that I was using (nihongo dera) said that both 「瞬く」 and 「煌めき」mean "to twinkle", but what's the difference between those two words?

Comment: What's the difference between a verb and a noun? Perhaps you are asking the difference between 煌めく and 瞬く?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

煌め**き** is the masu-stem of the verb 煌め**く**. This 煌めき is used as a noun ("twinkling thing"). See [masu-stem used as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). To be more specific, in this context, 煌めき seems to refer to twinkling/shiny *moments* in one's life.

As verbs, 瞬く and 煌めく are similar, but the former is focused on the quick brightness change, while the latter also describes something is bright/shiny.