# Should "obake" be understood to refer to shapeshifters, or rather to things which have been transformed?

Tags: etymology, semantics

In the [tvtropes article on Youkai](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Youkai), the following remark is made on the meaning of "obake":

> *Obake* is another Japanese word that can indicate some type of  monster. Derived from the word for "to change", it generally covers the  subset of youkai that includes shapeshifting animals (hence the terms *bake-gitsune*, *bake-neko*, etc.) as well as [Animate Inanimate Objects](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnimateInanimateObject) 〔i.e. *tsukumogami*〕. Confusingly, however, the word *obake* can also be used to refer to ghosts, also known as *yuurei*.

[The Wikipedia article on Yōkai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Dkai) contains the (unsourced) statement that

> *Yōkai* that shapeshift are known as *bakemono* (化け物) or [*obake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake) (お化け).

The [Wikipedia article on Obake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obake) contains the (unsourced) statement that

> Literally, the terms mean *a thing that changes*, referring to a state of transformation or [shapeshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapeshifting).

The implication that the *bakeru* root of obake/bakemono is related to the ability to shapeshift is a strong one at least as far as public opinion on the internet goes, despite the inconsistencies that can be noted with this etymology. In my estimation, the less incongruous root of the term would be that it refers to beings that *have undergone a change*; they might also (coincidentally) have shape-shifting powers. Many (perhaps not all) of the shape-shifting animals, which are considered *obake*, are transformations that happen when an animal has lived for a considerable amount of time (commonly 100 years); the *tsukumogami*, being items, commonly attain their status by considerable age as well, in particular by having been abandoned or forgotten or not well kept. In the case of *yurei*, the transition is that from the living to the dead. While this etymology seems to capture all of the cases that fall under *obake* (shapeshifting animals, animated items, ghosts), it would also exclude some other *yōkai* that are shapeshifters, but have not undergone a transformation, such as most prominently the *oni*, which ought to fall under *obake* if we considered it to refer to shapeshifting.

Is my reading of obake as referring to "transformed entity", rather than to "shapeshifter", a sensible one? Is there any support for it? Any credible scholarly sources that contravene it?

Comment: Your understanding should be fine, but I feel it's mostly a translation matter. お化け and 化ける are obviously related. Also, it is 'shapeshifted' rather than 'shapeshifter' (and don't read too much meaning in 'shape'),

Answer (score 2):

This may seem confusing and inconsistent if you analyze this based on the meaning of the English term "shapeshift", but it's not really a difficult concept.

In English, I think that "shapeshift" typically refers to significant transformations, such as a cat turning into a human or a human turning into a wolf (correct me if I'm wrong). However, the meaning of the verb 化ける (*bakeru*) in Japanese is somewhat broader. It can describe not only a cat transforming into a human, but also an umbrella or a cat transforming into their *yōkai* versions ([*kasa-obake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasa-obake) and *bake-neko*), as well as a human retaining their original form and becoming a ghost. For example, in a manga, it is common for a human character to say "私が死んだら化けて出てやる (If I die, I'll come back as a ghost/yūrei)!" using the verb *bakeru*.

Naturally, the range of what お化け (*obake*; a [noun version](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010) of 化ける) can refer to is quite extensive. It encompasses all sorts of creatures that have "an original form" such as a human, a fox, a cat, an umbrella, a pot, a lantern, and so on. When people say お化け without context, it typically refers to traditional Japanese creatures and human ghosts (*yūrei*) like [these](https://www.irasutoya.com/2013/08/blog-post_9820.html).

On the other hand, inherently unique creatures/species like *kappa*, *oni* and *tengu* are called *yōkai*, but they tend not to be referred to as *obake*. Note that an *oni* is not a shapeshifter just as western goblins and ogres aren't shapeshifters. That said, the boundaries between *yōkai* and *obake* are not always very strict, and different people may have slightly different ideas about them.

In the narrow sense of "shapeshift", such as when a human turns into a wolf or a cat turns into a human, people use 変身 (henshin). 変身 also includes transformations like a human becoming Spider-Man or Ultraman.